# Systematic error detection in data? Cleaning up?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector(s) of data which appears to have systematic errors, such as the figure below. This is a picture of the pressures from wind measured on a building at a point over a few hours. Is there a way of detecting whether these extreme values occur in a systematic way? And also cleaning it up to remove these spikes?

[image: Pressures]

Comment: Your systematic errors seems to have low frequency and very low pressure, you can either cut-off any data that has below 30 Pressure, or use the matlab filter to filter out the low frequency component (around 10Hz as it is - a high-pass filter).

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thank you. Could you clarify what you mean by matlab filter please? I'd like to remove these spikes altogether rather than cut them at -30 because...

Comment: when I say cut at -30, I mean that any data that is below 30 gets changed to 0, this would you fine in your case. To use the filter (in the frequency domain) look at http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html?refresh=true

Comment: @GameOfThrows Great link, thank you. Is there any way of identifying the frequency of the >-30 data do you think?

Comment: If you count its appearances, it happens around 10 times every 1*10^5 time unit, so it should have a frequency of around 10^-4 Hz - assuming that your time units are in seconds.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Hmmm definitely looks periodic, I'll look into the filter idea but I'm a bit wary because I don't want to incorporate these systematic errors into the data. I.e. i don't want to smooth it out, I just want to remove them.

Comment: As I mentioned, both the cut-off method and the filter method should work fine, if you want to try the cut-off simply do  result = data(find(data < -30))==0 should do the trick. The filtering is slightly more advanced.